# Primefaces Slider doesn't stop moving with mouse

Tags: jsf, primefaces, slider

I've inserted a Primefaces Slider on my page with very basic settings, the problem is once I click on its button, it doesn't stop moving with mouse. it doesn't a matter where in the page the mouse pointer is. The Slider button follows the mouse position to right or left. does any body an idea how to solve the problem?

```
<h:outputLabel styleClass="form-label-top-right" for="area">Area:
<h:outputText id="output" value="#{formbean.selectedArea}"/> Km
<h:inputHidden id="area" value="#{formbean.selectedArea}" />
<p:slider animate="true" display="output" minValue="0" maxValue="15" step="3" id="areaSlider" for="area" style="margin-top:6px; cursor: pointer" />
</h:outputLabel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved. It was the "FireQuery" Plugin for FireFox which caused the problem. uninstalling that

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the way you used h:outputLabel to contain these other tags not allowing the mouseup event to bubble up. Use a h:panelGrid with four columns instead.

For example:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="4">
    <h:outputLabel styleClass="form-label-top-right" for="output" value="Area:" />
    <h:panelGroup>
        <h:outputText id="output" value="#{formbean.selectedArea}"/>
        <h:outputText value="Km"/>
    </h:panelGroup>

        <h:inputHidden id="area" value="#{formbean.selectedArea}" />
        <p:slider animate="true" display="output" minValue="0" maxValue="15" step="3" id="areaSlider" for="area" style="margin-top:6px; cursor: pointer" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Thank you @Ravi but it didn't work. I think the trigger to stop moving doesn't work properly, as I'm getting these 2 Warnings on Console: 1. No elements were found with the selector: ":input,option"
jquery...mefaces
2. trigger([object Object],[object Object]) called incorrectly

Comment: Which version of PF and browser are you using? Also do you have any other javascript code that you are trying to manipulate things.